# Does Xcode have a way to force the editor to display intellisense options?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Many times when I am coding, I get the intellisense, but then I press the backspace key once to delete a character, and then the intellisense goes away.

Is there a keyboard shortcut to force it to come back?

Also, when intellisense first displays with its recommendation, how can I cycle through the other possibilities?

Answer (score 7):

Hit the escape key. That's the universal shortcut for the "completion" feature in any of the Cocoa app. The escape key shows the "intellisense" (TM) in Xcode, but it shows completion of English words in Text Edit, etc.

Answer (score 4):

Escape or `Ctrl+,` will pop up the list.  You can also cycle through possibilities in-place with `Ctrl+.` (forward) and `Ctrl+Shift+.` (backward).